# how do I limit a period of time

Tags: php, mysql

What i want to do is to limit a user to deposit/withdraw money in the account only 5 times a week , and after the 5 times user must wait next week to be able to deposit again.
I have a table named depuser with the following rows : uid(userid), date(date of dep/witdraw), type(deposit/witdraw) and the amount. thanks in advance

Comment: and your question is? Because it seems like you are seeking for some free coding service, which doesn't happen here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will count the # of deposits recorded in the last 7 days, based on your table structure:

```
SELECT COUNT(uid) AS total_deposits FROM depuser 
WHERE `type` LIKE 'deposit' AND 
DATE(`date`) <= NOW() AND 
DATE(`date`) >= DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)`
```

From here you can compare the total_deposits value returned and make logic decisions.

Comment: i made like this , but i get : Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean